# Как правильно обеспечить работу Z-index между страницей и iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

На сайте есть окно(div), оно должно быть поверх iframe блока, но внутри iframe тоже есть окна, некоторые из которых должны быть поверх этого первого окна.

Как правильно это реализовать, чтобы корректно работал Z-index?

Сейчас я выставляю у первого окна Z равный 15, а у окна внутри iframe 200.
Однако он по прежнему выводится под первым окном.

Comment: ваша страница и внутренности фрейма это разные DOM-деревья, их контент вы никак компоновать не можете и доступ внутрь не имеете.

Comment: Почитай вот такую статью - https://habr.com/ru/articles/431046/

Comment: То есть никак не получится накладывать окна самой страницы и iframe между собой?

Comment: к з-индекс попробуй добавить позиционирование, там по разному можно элементы подвигать на странице